# Extracting in shiny server value of a variable sent by url without using it in ui.R

Tags: r, shiny

I am beginner with shiny. I wrote an app which works fine, ploting survival curves from a medical data base. After connection to the data base, selected items are stored in a f1 data-table. No problem.

But then I want to make a selection of records with the name of the country sent by the URL of the browser calling the app. I read lots of contributions and I know questions on close subject were sent, but none of the answers correspond exactly to my problem.

Here is part of my server.R code. I do not know how to extact from the output query text (lines 24-31) the country variable to make the selection. In addition the best way would be to have the possibility to make the selection before connecting to the data base (first lines) so that I would not have to download the whole data base and make the selection later on.

I am not totally fluent in english, I hope my question is clear.

Thank you in advance for your assistance

CV

```
 #Server.R

library(shiny)
library(survival)
library(RMySQL)
drv=dbDriver("MySQL")
con = dbConnect(drv, user="myname", password="mypassword", dbname="mydatabase",host="localhost")
req=paste("SELECT variable1,variable2,country, from mydatabase-file") 
f1=dbGetQuery(con,req)
dbDisconnect(con)

# Define server logic required to generate survival plot on criteria selection

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

#++++++ start of the not working part of code +++++

# here I want to make a selection using the url sent by the browser
parseQueryString("?country=France") # just for test, normally from  the URL
 # Parse the GET query string
output$queryText <- renderText({
query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
selectcriteria<-output$queryText

f2<-f1[f1$country==output$queryText,] ##### does not work, 
## I know it is not possible this way so how can i do it ? 

#+++++++++ end of the not working code ++++

#### doing the job, following lines work fine..
output$barrePlot <- renderPlot({

##  etc....doing different things...


})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

The `output$queryText` will hold the renderText function and not the string itself, so you can't use it to subset your data.

You could use a reactive expression to store the parsed query and use that to subset your data etc.

For example:

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {
  f1<-data.frame(country=rep(c("France","UK"),6),age=runif(12)) 

  user_query <- reactive({
    query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
    query[["country"]]
  })

  f2 <- reactive({
    data <- f1[f1$country==user_query(),]
    data$country <- factor(data$country)
    data
  })

  output$queryText <- renderText({

    paste("Mean: ", mean(f2()$age),"Number of rows: ",length(f2()$age))
    #you could also do
    #paste("Mean: ", mean(f1[f1$country==user_query(),]$age),"Number of rows: ",length(f1[f1$country==user_query(),]$age))
  })

  output$plot <- renderPlot({        
    if(!is.null(user_query())) plot(f2()$country,f2()$value)
  })

})
```

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(bootstrapPage(
verbatimTextOutput("queryText"),
  plotOutput("plot")
))
```

Note that reactive expressions are functions, so to get the value you have to call the function (for ex. `user_query()`)

Comment: Sorry instead of using comment I answered my own question. I tried your code and your example worked fine. However, probably missing some basic knowledge in this field I could not solve my problem, as I did not underdstand perfectly your explanation. How can i process for example some thing as result<-mean(f1$value[country=="France"] by sending the country from the calling url query. Or make a usable subset of f1 with the the country sent by the subset, then send the result with renderText. Thank you idvance for you help.

Comment: I edited the `renderText` part of the answer, you can subset `f2()` to get the mean or get the data from f1 again. If you call `user_query()` or `f2()` you have to be in a [reactive expression](http://shiny.rstudio.com/tutorial/lesson6/) such as `renderText`, so it's easier to do all the calculations in there. If you plan on reusing the mean somewhere else and want to keep it in a variable, you can do `age_mean <- reactive({ mean(f2()$age) })` and then do `print(age_mean())` in the `renderText`

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your rapid answer. I could make your example running fine. However I still do not understand how to use it.

For example in the following example suppose there is in the data.frame f1 the age of the subjects and the country, such as f1$age and f1$country. I want to calculate the mean age of french and the number of french.

I need a subset of f1, lets call it f1b. In R I would right  :

f1b<-f1[f1$country=="FRANCE",]

m<-mean(f1b$age)

nb<-length(f1b$age)

How can i do it in the following code ?

```
#f1<-data.frame with variables f1$age et f1$country             
user_query <- reactive({
query <- parseQueryString(session$clientData$url_search)
query[["country"]]
})

f2 <- reactive({
data <- f1[f1$country==user_query(),]
data$country <- factor(data$country)
data
})
# here how can I obtain the subset file f1b to calclate m and nb as folows?
m<-mean(f1b$age)
nb<-length(f1b$age)

  output$queryText <- renderText({print(m,nb))

})
})
```